# Download update using a link in Advanced Installer

Tags: updates, advanced-installer

I have created an installer using Advanced Installer.I am trying to download an update using updater.exe and test it,but it gave me an error.I added a public DropBox link from where it should fetch the update.What could be the issue?

Please help

Thanks

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with Dropbox should work without a problem. First test the public link you get from Dropbox into a webbrowse, to see the files can be downloaded. If this works post a screenshot with the error you get so we can have more details.

Comment: Hi @Bogdan Mitrache.The dropbox link is a public link and it works fine.But when I try downloading the update via updater.exe it gives we the following error
This is the link:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/suk0buqumxhl6ek/a6.jpg)

Kindly check the above link and let me know

Comment: this error appears because you have incorrectly configured the updater. The updates.txt file must be generated by Advanced Installer and placed usually next to your new package. Point the updater to it, after the updater downloads and reads this file it will start downloading the new package. Take a closer look here: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updater-diagram.html

Comment: I dint know that @Bogdan Mitrache.Thanks.Will try it

Comment: How and when will the Advanced Installer generate updates.txt file.I even saved a file called updates.txt to dropbox and tried downloading it using the installer,but I am getting the same error.

Comment: please follow the tutorials, otherwise you are wasting your time trying options like this http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-updater.html

Comment: I followed the tutorial generated updates.txt using updates configuration project,uploaded it to dropbox but I am getting the same error as mentioned above and why is this so much tricky